# Which is correct: "on foot" or "by foot"?

Tags: prepositions, collocations, idiomatic-language

> He went there **on** foot.

Or

> He went there **by** foot.

Which one is correct, and on what basis?

Comment: [here's an Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+on+foot%2C+there+by+foot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20on%20foot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20by%20foot%3B%2Cc0), and [here's another](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=traveled+on+foot%2C+traveled+by+foot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctraveled%20on%20foot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctraveled%20by%20foot%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @CopperKettle interesting! My first instinct was actually "by foot," as in, "He travelled there by foot," but the Ngram clearly shows "on foot" being much more popular.

Comment: Here is the Ngram for **[went there on (by) foot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+there+on+foot%2C+went+there+by+foot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20there%20on%20foot%3B%2Cc0)** -- zero results for **on**

Comment: @CopperKettle [went on foot,went by foot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+on+foot%2Cwent+by+foot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20on%20foot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20by%20foot%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

'On foot' is the more commonly used expression.This also stems from the fact that 'on' is usually used for actions involving body parts.

'By' is usually used to talk about a means of transport (i.e. train, car, boat, plane, etc).

They both have the same meaning, albeit with different grammatical structure.

> We can use say both – with these justifications:

- Why you should say ***on foot***

> We usually use *on* for movements or actions that involve using body parts. You can rest on your elbows, you can pray on your knees, and you can lie on your back. Walking is no different – the action takes place **on foot**.

- Why you could say ***by foot***

> We use *by* to describe a tool used for movements or actions. You can *travel by plane*, *by boat* or *by car*, for instance. You can send letters *by post*, and you can write *by hand*. It stands to reason, then, that you can *travel **by** foot*.

- So which is more correct?

> You move with your feet in contact with the ground, supported by your feet, making *on* foot a more literal description of the action. Yet your feet are also a tool of sorts, so if we want to describe what you use to travel, *by foot* makes perfect sense. It is not reasonable, then, to say one is more correct than the other. Yet you may be told that *by foot* is incorrect. Why? For the same reason that many rules exist in English:
>
> *Because **‘on foot’ is more commonly used** than by foot.*

Source: [English Lessons Brighton](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/say-on-foot-by-foot/)

The following links also explore the problem in depth:
[“By foot” vs. “on foot”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17943/by-foot-vs-on-foot) (EL&U)
http://www.icaltefl.com/on-foot-vs-by-foot